# Microsoft Access can't represent the join expression

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I received the error mentioned in the title, and now my Access query will not open in design view. I checked the SQL Statement for any reserved characters, but I can't seem to find any. This leaves me truly stumped, and any input (or an explanation) would be helpful!

the SQL Query is as follows:

```
SELECT dbo_REP_PROFILE.CRD_NUMBER, dbo_CONTACT.FIRST_NAME, dbo_CONTACT.MIDDLE_NAME
, dbo_CONTACT.LAST_NAME, dbo_REP_ALIAS.FIRM_ID, dbo_REP_ALIAS.OFFICE_ID
, dbo_REP_ALIAS.TRADE_REP, dbo_CONTACT_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_LINE_1
, dbo_CONTACT_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_LINE_2, dbo_REP_ALIAS.CONTACT_ID
, dbo_REP_ALIAS.PRIMARY_YN, dbo_CONTACT.BUSINESS_PHONE
, dbo_CONTACT.EMAIL_ADDRESS 
INTO [SalesPage Reps]
FROM ((dbo_CONTACT 
INNER JOIN dbo_REP_ALIAS ON dbo_CONTACT.CONTACT_ID=dbo_REP_ALIAS.CONTACT_ID) 
INNER JOIN dbo_REP_PROFILE ON dbo_REP_ALIAS.CONTACT_ID=dbo_REP_PROFILE.CONTACT_ID)  
INNER JOIN dbo_CONTACT_ADDRESS ON (dbo_CONTACT.CONTACT_ID=dbo_CONTACT_ADDRESS.CONTACT_ID) 
AND (dbo_CONTACT_ADDRESS.CONTACT_ADDRESS_ID=dbo_CONTACT.ADDRESS_1_ID)
WHERE (((dbo_REP_PROFILE.CRD_NUMBER) Is Not Null) 
AND ((dbo_REP_ALIAS.CONTACT_ID) Is Not Null) 
AND ((dbo_REP_ALIAS.PRIMARY_YN)='Y'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a known issue in MS access, and here is the cause and resolution for the same.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/207868

Comment: Like @Sonam here is suggesting, I think it's all those unnecessary parenthesis, especially the 2 right after `From`. Try taking them all out (yes, even if they were added by Access automatically) and then try the design view again.

Comment: Once again, "Gates' SQL" makes easy things hard :( That's why I moved away from Access

Comment: This issue can also be caused by leading tab characters.  In an effort to make my code more readable, I added a leading tab character to certain key words.  Apparently sometimes Access ignores them, and in others it choked.